# Working with J1 SSN on B1-B2 visa, questions about possible problems

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I have B1-B2 visa and I work in USA on my J1 SSN. In 15 days I go back to my home country. In two months i return to USA again, also on B1-B2 visa. I was getting paid in checks which were taxed properly on my SSN.

Could I have problems on my return to USA in two months? Because technically I shouldn't work on B1-B2 but I didn't have problem finding jobs just with my SSN.

Comment: Did you work as an employee or independent contractor? If you worked as an employee, the employer should have had you fill out an I-9 when you started work, and you should not have been able to provide the documents to satisfy the I-9.

Comment: @user102008 although I've recently seen a comment from someone who said he had an unrestricted SSN card from an earlier period in some nonimmigrant status.  I presume the card was supposed to have been restricted.  The implication was that the SSA isn't extremely precise about issuing cards to nonimmigrants.

Comment: The employer has violated immigration law (of course so did you).

Answer (score 3):

> I have B1-B2 visa and I work in USA on my J1 SSN.

The Social Security Number has nothing to do with your immigration status.  Once you have a number, it's yours for life, but the *fact that you have a number does not imply that you are authorized to work in the US.*

> I was getting paid in checks which were taxed properly on my SSN.

The fact that income taxes were withheld also does not mean that everything about your working in the US was legal.  It just means that your employer has complied with the laws concerning tax withholding.

> Could I have problems on my return to USA in two months? Because technically I shouldn't work on B1-B2 but I didn't have problem finding jobs just with my SSN.

Yes, you could have problems, because, as you note, you are not allowed to work in the US while you are in B-1 or B-2 status.  The fact that an employer hired you does not excuse you from the obligation to comply with the conditions of your immigration status.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you tell me some specific problems that could occur? Could they stop me from entering the USA?

Comment: @Vizzle yes, they can.  They will also revoke your visa because when you violated your B visitor status it became invalid.

Comment: Well I may be wrong about the automatic invalidity of the visa from the status violation; that seems to result only from an overstay.  There's nonetheless a very high likelihood that they'll revoke it under one of the provisions of [22 CFR 41.122(e)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/41.122#e).

Comment: @Vizzle: Yes, they can deny you entry. And then, they can choose to "remove" you instead of letting you leave on your own, and if they "remove" you, that triggers a 5-year ban. Also, as phoog said, they can revoke your visa.